Querying Redis for Horizon Values
I'm trying to query Redis for Horizon's pending jobs. I can see the laravel_horizon:pending_jobs entry in "sorted sets" when I am browsing Redis with PhpStorm's database tool.
If I double-click the entry, I can see a list of values and scores. I can see the same result by running zrange laravel_horizon:pending_jobs 0 -1 withscores in the PhpStorm's Redis query console.
I can see the key laravel_horizon:pending_jobs in the returned array when using both the connection specific scan() as well as the facade:
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;
dump(Redis::scan(null));
$redis = Redis::connection('horizon');
dump($redis->scan(null));

However, if I run this, I get an empty array:
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;
$redis = Redis::connection('horizon');
dump($redis->zRange('laravel_horizon:pending_jobs', 0, -1));

I also get an empty array when using the Redis facade directly:
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;
dump(Redis::zRange('laravel_horizon:pending_jobs', 0, -1));

I'm probably missing something very basic. I don't have much experience interacting with Redis. I'm also likely overcomplicating it.

Why are you trying to read that value? What are you trying to achieve with it? You do have a UI, can't you use it?

@matiaslauriti I'm trying to do it programatically. If Horizon can get the values, I should be able to as well.
